# url rewriting with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the url  on a site I have on localhost (port 8000), I have already set this up for certain other directorys but I can't manage to do it for this one. I compared it to several other working .htaccess files but there wasn't any difference. (The module is activated.) The site is in a subdirectory called HTF and the file single.php works just fine. The htaccess file is placed in the same directory.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule videos/([0-9]+)/$ /HTF/single.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I would like to get an url like  localhost:8000/HTF/video/1232434 for exemple. 
Any help appreciated, tested several types of htacces files, here a working exemple for a other subdirectory called sorted:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^image-post/([0-9]+)/(.+)\.php$ /sorted/image-post.php?   id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]+)/(.+)\.php$ /sorted/page.php?page_number=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 localhost:8000/HTF/video/1232434
```

will not match

```
 videos/([0-9]+)/$
```

because of the trailing slash `/`. Try `/?` to make the slash optional or leave away. And video**s**.

```
^/HTF/video/([0-9]+)/?$ /HTF/single.php?id=$1 [L]
```

or

```
^/HTF/video/([0-9]+)$ /HTF/single.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This shall do the job. *Sorry can not try here.*

Comment: sadly not working, the page displays as wanted but the url is not changing.   I would also be happy with /HTF/2343545 as rewritten url for exemple..

Comment: If such a rule is not working the way you expect if may collide with an `Alias` in `httpd.conf` or others. Have you checked? Set `RewriteLog "/var/www/mod_rewrite.log"` and `RewriteLogLevel 2` (or higher) and read logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will match videos, not video as you were wanting. Also it will only match with a trailing slash.
This will work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/?$ single.php?id=$1
```

Comment: sadly not working, the page displays as wanted but the url is not changing.   I would also be happy with /HTF/2343545 as rewritten url for exemple..

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the URL not changing? That rewrite rule will show the contents of /HTF/single.php?id=123 when you visit /HTF/video/123